# Why VS2010 stops on COMException if exists a try catch and the exception settings is set to not throw on first-chance

Tags: c#, .net, exception, comexception

I have the following code:

```
try
{
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.axWebBrowser1)).EndInit();
}
catch
{
}
```

And I have the Exception dialog configured to not stop on anything handled:

[image]

Anyway VS stops on the following exception and execution cannot continue. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the settings section for the debugger there is a checkbox for "[Break when exceptions cross AppDomain or managed/native boundaries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85yzd16c.aspx)", that is why the catch is not being used.